# Failure to communicate events between components

Tags: angular

I have got this class that acts as a mediator:

```
 export class ProgressBarService {

  // Observable string sources
  private progressAnnouncement = new Subject<number>();

  // Observable string streams
  progressAnnounced$ = this.progressAnnouncement.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  AdministerProgress(progress: number) {
    this.progressAnnouncement.next(progress);
  }
}
```

Component A sends a message like this in ngOnInit:

```
  this.progressBarService.AdministerProgress(100);
```

But it never gets to the navigational component:

```
 constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    private requestBuilder: RequestBuilder,
    private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private router: Router,
    private progressBarService: ProgressBarService ) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
 
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.progressBarService.progressAnnounced$.subscribe(announcement => {
      console.log(announcement);
      this.progressBarValue = announcement;
      this.cdref.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

I get no message for the console.log. Why is that?
**UPDATE**
I followed this explanation
[Behavior subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject)

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProgressBarService {

  // Observable string sources
  public progressAnnouncement$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);


  constructor() { }

  AdministerProgress(progress: number) {
    console.info('inside func',progress);
    this.progressAnnouncement$.next(progress);
  }
}
```

The navigation header of the page which loads first subscribes:

```
    ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.progressBarService.progressAnnouncement$.subscribe(announcement => {
      console.info('Announcement', announcement);
      this.progressBarValue = announcement;
      this.cdref.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

Then another component that loads much later emits values by using the AdministerProgress function, as such:

```
    this.progressBarService.AdministerProgress(100);
```

The header component never receives the 100 value. All it gets are many 0 values one after the other.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the shared class:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProgressBarService {

  public progressAnnouncement$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  constructor() { }

  AdministerProgress(progress: number) {
    this.progressAnnouncement$.next(progress);
  }
}
```

Here is the singleton module that I created, as was explained in this link:

> https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service

```
    import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ProgressBarService } from 'app/Services/Classes/ProgressBarServices/ProgressBarService';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class SingletonModule {

  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule?: SingletonModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        'SingletonModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
    }
  }

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<SingletonModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: SingletonModule,
      providers: [
        ProgressBarService
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

This is the section of my app.module where I import that module:

```
  imports: [
CommonModule,
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatsharedModule,
HttpClientModule,
SharedModule,
PrimeNGModule,
LayoutModule,
SingletonModule.forRoot(),
```

Here is my main AppRoutingModule config file:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './Dashboard/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './Errors/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './Services/Guards/auth.guard';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'authentication',
    loadChildren: () => import('./authentication/authentication.module').then(m => m.AuthenticationModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'accounting',
    loadChildren: () => import('./accounting/accounting.module').then(m => m.AccountingModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () => import('./users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'game-management',
    loadChildren: () => import('./game-management/game-management.module').then(m => m.GameManagementModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'operator',
    loadChildren: () => import('./operator-management/operator-management.module').then(m => m.OperatorManagementModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'technical',
    loadChildren: () => import('./technical/technical.module').then(m => m.TechnicalModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
   {
   // enableTracing: true,// <-- debugging purposes only
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  }
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The other module dont have a trace of the service provided or the singleton module imported.

I believe that I miss some configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the `navigation component` subscribe to the Observable after `component A` fire the data, which mean it miss the data.

The solution is to change `progressAnnouncement` from `Subject` to [`BehaviorSubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) or [`ReplaySubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject). Each of those two have slighly different use but the main different from `Subject` is they store the data inside and new subscribers always have the latest data (`BehaviorSubject`) or all the data emitted (`ReplaySubject`).

**Update :**

In case of layzy-loading, there change that both component using different instances of the same service, the most easy way is to mark the service as app-wide singleton using `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` pattern. You can [read more about singleton service in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service) here.

Comment: @LastGrip When you first subscribe, did it log 0 to console ? or do you lazy loading the navigation header ?

Comment: Or could you create a stackbliz example ? if it not firing then the case you have is not a common case, and there still something missing from your minimal reproduce.

Comment: I load the component in a lazy way. I will double check if I can reproduce it in stackbliz. I do suspect howwever, that it is because of lazy loading of the components. How can I communicate in case of lazy loading?

Comment: Yeah it is, I suspect that you providing the service in both module or just the child module. In this case you must use the `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` instead of declare inside providers to mark the service as app-wide singleton

Comment: You can read more about it here https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service

Comment: The singleton pattern didnt work. But I believe that I am close to the solution. See update.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. I had the service provided also in the navigation component decorator. That what lead to two services instantiating.